# How to join two ID columns with another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables like below,

Match table

| date | team1 | team2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/2/2019 | t001 | t002 |
| 3/2/2019 | t007 | t002 |

Team table

| teamID | teamName |
| --- | --- |
| t001 | ABCD |
| t002 | EFGH |
| t003 | IJKL |
| t007 | MNOP |

I want to display Match table with teamName of team1 and team2 instead of teamID. I know I can join it as,

```
SELECT m.date, t.teamName, t.team2 
FROM Match m INNER JOIN Team t 
ON t.team1 = t.teamID;
```

But it can join with only one column. I don't know how to join both columns. Is there anyway to do this.

Comment: Which is it: MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; you will need to [edit] your question to (re)tag the (R)DBMS you are *actually* using.

Comment: Just join again using a *different* alias.

Comment: @tadman it's MySql

Comment: @PM77-1 Then how to display it in SELECT clause. Please can you explain it little bit. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: why do you have in Team1 and Team2 in the Team table. If in your chart they are in the table Match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT m.date, t.teamName, t1.teamName
    FROM Match m INNER JOIN Team t 
    ON m.team1 = t.teamID
    FROM Match m1 INNER JOIN Team t1 
    ON m1.team2 = t1.teamID;
```

or

```
    SELECT m.date, t.teamName, t1.teamName
       FROM Match m 
       INNER JOIN Team t ON m.team1 = t.teamID
       INNER JOIN Team t1 ON m.team2 = t1.teamID;
```

It's the same

I don't understand the table name, why is a d.team2 if there is no alias d,. And why are team1 and team2 both also from table d.
But if I veratanden your two tables correctly the bottom query works.
But for multible joins you can just use different alias.

Comment: I suggest you replace `m.team2` with `t1.teamName`.

Comment: Thank you, for SELECT I have the same things as he used above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry about 'd'. It is my mistake. It should be corrected as 't'. Can we have two from clauses in a query? Sorry for asking. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: With this query you get the date and the name of the team. Sry but I do not understand exactly what you want

Comment: And  on your query is t.team2 do you mean t1.teamName. t1 = the other join

Comment: @lesch Thank you for helping me. I got your answer.

Comment: If it works please mark at answered. If it not work please ask question